# Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 and reinstall windows 8

Tags: 12.04, windows, uninstall

I bought an Hp computer a few weeks ago second hand and it has ubuntu 12.04 installed onto it. The guy i bought it off gave me the installation cd he used to put it on the computer but i really dont like it, i want to get windows back on the computer but have no idea how an earth to do that, i have a product key for windows 8 but no installation disk for it. HOW DO I REINSTALL WINDOWS AND UNINSTALL UBUNTU?????

Answer (score 0):

First: you will have to get the "iso" file for the windows 8 distribution you intend to use.
Second:you must burn this image to a dvd (at least 5gb)
Third: after inserting your new windows installation disk, reboot your system and go into BIOS.
Fourth: navigate to the "boot" menu and move your optical drive up to the top (that way you will be able to boot from the disk you just made.

after that, just follow the windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what to do. And I am sorry to answer this later, I thought I answered before...

Anyway, does your printer support the wifi connection? If yes, if both your computer and your printed are connected to the wifi, you must click on the dash, then write "printer", then you could set up your printer thanks to the network option. Always works!

If you do not have that wifi option, you could use the ethernet wire to connect your computer to your modem, and connect connect your printer to the same modem. To make sure your printer will work, also connect the USB wire to your laptop...

I think that method will work for you. Do not forget to add the printer in the printer's settings!

Comment: all i want to do is print. i have tried everything and the printer won't connect to the computer, i have tried every usb port in the computer and going to settings-printing-add and followed the promps it added my printer but when i go to print nothing happens, i can photocopy off the printer and that works i have tried to download hplip but its not downloading on my computer im very frustrated. i know how to use windows ive used it my whole life ive never used ubuntu before i have version 12.04 and i have an hp desktop computer and an hp deskjet 3520 series printer i just want to print!!!!!